# Bigquery API python script returns no data in batch mode

Tags: python, batch-file, google-api, google-bigquery

I wrote a basic script to grab my GA import (data of yesterday) from Bigquery in the morning (6AM, UTC).
I ran it literally humdreds of times myself and I'm calling it the exact same way as I do in crontab.

Yet, one time out of two, the API call to the Bigquery API returns no data.

Have you experienced such issue?

@EDIT: sorry, i sent a slightly truncated messsage.
The code I use is more or less the official one available here:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/data

```
service=get_service('bigquery', 'v2', scope, key_file_location, service_account_email)
#query_request = service.jobs()
query_response = sync_query(service,project_id, sql_query)
results = []
page_token = None
while True:
    page = service.jobs().getQueryResults(
        pageToken=page_token,
        **query_response['jobReference']).execute(num_retries=2)
    results.extend(page.get('rows', []))
    page_token = page.get('pageToken')
    if not page_token:
        break
```

And here is there sync_query():

```
def sync_query(bigquery, project_id, query, timeout=60000, num_retries=5):
    query_data = {
        'query': query,
        'timeoutMs': timeout,
    }
    return bigquery.jobs().query(
        projectId=project_id,
        body=query_data).execute(num_retries=num_retries)
```

Will try to increase the parameter even more

Comment: can you share with us your script for using gbc api?

Comment: For the people interested: I schedule the script every 15min and realized our the dataset is created every morning ramdomly between 8.30 and 10:00 GMT+1......